# PHP PDO MySQL Access Denied on Create Table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

User can login via PHP PDO user, password, database and select, insert, update.

But on Create table fails with access denied error. Same user can log in via MySQL client and create table.

Grant shows that user@localhost has create privileges for the database.

How do I start diagnosing this issue?

Comment: Remote and local users may have different privileges. Are you sure you're connection the same way in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in mysql users are granted based on host where the user will try to access the db. Look into you mysql.user table.
The application might be deployed at host 1 therefore using user A@host1, and on login to MySQL client at host2 you are using user A@host2.
These have different permissions in users table. So I suggest to start by looking there

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of "little" errors in my code. All the responses got me looking in the right places.
Probably the main one was my misunderstanding of the connection to the database. Since the user was logged in to a database I assumed the CREATE TEMP Table would create it there. It didn't - it needed an explicit database.

Thanks for all the suggestions

Frank P